# swift: what's type "(AnyObject)"?

Tags: swift

I'm running into a very interesting error message today:

> Cannot invoke 'map' with an argument list of type '(AnyObject)'

I don't even know there is an type in Swift called (AnyObject)!

---

the context is, I'm using a closure as a callback after an http request:

```
dataHandler: ((AnyObject) -> ())?,
```

and trying to get implement the dataHandler in this piece of code:

```
dataHandler: { (obj: AnyObject) -> () in ...}
```

at this moment, swift take "obj" as type: (Anyobject)...

---

Thanks for @sketchyTech's inspiring answer, ObjectMapper seems need concrete type of "AnyObject", like cast it into Array or Dictionary. Now my code works:

```
    if let dic = res as? [String: AnyObject], res = Mapper<MappableType>().map(dic) {
        ...
    }
```

Comment: You need to cast your `obj` to the appropriate type (or maybe parse it if it's a JSON or XML response). AnyObject is what it sounds like - any object!

Comment: thanks for your response, yes, you are right. I'm using ObjectMapper, and I realized, mapper is not working on "any" object.

Comment: What type do you need it to be?  An array or a dictionary?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When used as a concrete type, rather than a generic type, `AnyObject` enables you to call any ObjC method (but of course it must be able to respond to the method at runtime to avoid crashing).

> When used as a concrete type, all known `@objc` methods and
>   properties are available, as implicitly-unwrapped-optional methods
>   and properties respectively, on each instance of `AnyObject`. (Swift header file)

Its primary role is to help with passing objects between ObjC and the strongly-typed language of Swift.

For an instance of type `AnyObject` to be used with higher order Swift functions it must first be cast to a type to which they can be applied, e.g.

```
dataHandler: {arr in
    if let a = arr as? [Int] {
        a.map{$0+1}
    }}
```

Comment: thank you so much! yes, I need an Dictionary, and this surely helped me out of this. Thank you so much!

Comment: for a Dictionary you can write the following: `{dict in if let d = dict as? [String:Int] {a.map{(k,v) in print(v)}}}` but of course if it is an NSDictionary that you receive of mixed types then you will need to take account of that and perhaps use `[String:AnyObject]` for example to find something that it will cast to.

Comment: I'm not using swift Native .map(), but your answer really was inspiring, now it works like this:            if let dic = obj as? [String: AnyObject], res = Mapper<Type>().map(dic) {